# groovy script SOAP UI json response parse

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui, assertions

How to parse `json` response using groovy script.

I am using SOAP UI and have json response as below-

```
{ 
    "resource": {
        "name":"aaaaaaaaaaa",
        "emailid":"bbbbbbbbb"
    }
}
```

Can anyone please share sample code to parse json object and post that some basic assertions check.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Script Assertion` for the rest request test step with below script.

- Define your expected data as shown in the snippet below as needed
- It compares each key value with expected data.

`JsonSlurper` can be used to parse the response.

```
//Check if the response is not empty
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

//Define expected data
def expectedData = [name: 'aaaaaaaaaaa', emailid: 'bbbbbbbbb']

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)
//Checks all elements of resource one by one and compare with expectedData
json.resource.each {k, v -> assert v == expectedData."$k" }
```